# What is a word for 'reverse' homesick? Not wanting to go back

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for *reverse homesickness*?

Let's say, if you visit a place, and you like it so much, you don't want to leave.

Comment: It's simple. **Sick of home**.

Comment: Is the place Hotel California?

Comment: @NVZ: Oh, I don't think they *liked* it so much they didn't want to leave. "Next thing I remember, I was running for the door." ;-)

Comment: Jane - "Wanderlust" is definitely **not** the answer to the question above. People with wanderlust don't just leave *home* and then stay elsewhere; they leave *everywhere*. They never stay in one place for long.

Comment: @NVZ - you wouldn't be sick of home if you hadn't been there in a while though, which is the OP's context.

Comment: @MaxWilliams It was more like a joke.  :)

Comment: @NVZ ah, are they allowed now then? ;-)

Comment: How about "happy".

Comment: There are two reasons for not wanting to go home; are you repulsed by home OR more fond of some new place?

Comment: @duanev: Surely the second (last) sentence of the question makes the answer to that clear? *"Let's say, if you visit a place, and you like it so much, you don't want to leave."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  The author's *example* is clear but a standalone phrase for reverse homesickness will be ambiguous unless it implies an attraction or revulsion relative to the two locales.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/magazine/life-around-world/opposite-homesickness
referring to this link... The opposite of homesick is "Wanderlust" when you have a big desire for traveling or going to a journey and exploring the world.
However there was an interesting comment in a forum about the opposite of homesickness:

It's still homesick.

"Boy, I am homesick!"

"But you live at home."

"Yeah, and I'm sick of it!"

hope it helps

Comment: I like this answer, as it provides a clean, symmetrical meaning: "homesick" = always wanting to return TO one's home; "wanderlust" = always wanting to return to your travels AWAY from one's home.

Comment: I like this too, although it's not necessary applicable to wanting to stay in any one non-home location (as asked for in the question). Someone with wanderlust will get itchy in the new place too.

Comment: But "wanderlust" means you enjoy the journey. How does this apply when you **don't** want to leave somewhere? I can't really see it applying if someone found their favorite place and never left...I wouldn't say they have a wanderlust.

Comment: "Wanderlust" doesn't work for the example in the question, which is more like "fell in love with [place they visited]". "Wanderlust" (like "itchy feet") is more like falling *out* of love with where you are and wanting to go somewhere else (not anywhere specific)

Comment: Consider also "[Fernweh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fernweh)".

Comment: *Wanderlust* does not really fit. It would mean, wanting to stay travelling, not settling down. But the OP describes a situation, where she wants to stay in a particular place rather than return to her original home (*homesickness*) or resume her journeys (*wanderlust*). OP wants to make the current place her new home, settling down there.

Answer (score 18):

What you describe isn't quite the opposite of homesickness, though I can see how you got there. Homesickness is wanting to be at home when you aren't. The opposite of that would be wanting to be elsewhere when you're at home (wanderlust), but that's not at all the same thing as "liking a place so much you don't want to leave."

I don't think there is a single term that captures both the reality and mood you're describing. There are various phrases used in relation to this:

- *going native* - "to start to behave or live like the local people <After a few weeks, she was comfortable enough to go native and wear shorts to work.>" [(M-W)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20native) - beware this can have negative connotations in some situations.
- *settling* - "to move to a place and make it your home" [(M-W)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settle)
- *(happily) adopting a new home*

...but none quite hits the mood aspect. I don't think there's a single term that does.

Comment: +1, this is what I had in mind. There's no single word for OP's question. :)

Answer (score 6):

The search for antonyms of “homesick” was not very useful for your application, specifically:

> Let's say if you visit a place and **you like it so much** ***you do not want to leave?***

This often happens to people who go on vacation to a place so different and care-free that they never want to leave. Possibly it is a form of *vacationitis*.

The definition of a person who has renounced his homeland and taken up residence in another country is an [ex-patriate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expatriate), and the condition is **ex-patriatism**; however, it doesn’t quite fit here.

A person who experienced the sensation you describe was [Jimmy Buffet](http://www.margaritaville.com/about-jimmy). He left his home and went to Nashville, but did not feel very productive there. By accident he ended up in Key West, and felt so comfortable that he began to produce his most famous songs, one of which was “**I Have Found Me a Home**”.

He also wrote what is probably his most famous hit, “**Margaritaville**”.

> [Term coined](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Margaritaville) by bored individual (e.g. the Author) as the ultimate getaway paradise.
>
> "Wasting away again in **Margaritaville**."
>
> "Some day, I'll sweep you off your feet, and we'll spend the rest of our decadent, happy lives in Margaritaville."

So, although the word does not exist, I would like to suggest ***Margaritaville-itis.***

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a true antonym as such, but you might say:

> He went, and never looked back!

or:

> Oh wow, this has ruined home for me.

or you might just rave about what an awesome holiday you had, and let it be taken as read that it was better than home. (Else why go, right?)

Comment: And the other travellers came riding down the track
And they never went further, no, they never went back

Answer (score 0):

**Rooted** I think comes to mind off hand as a word I might use in prose to describe a character finally feeling he is now at home, in a new place.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
*A suggestion is not an answer.*
A good answer is comprehensive and contains an explanation of ***why*** it is correct.
Also, do not answer questions which are unclear, out of scope, or already answered many times before. The question lacks evidence of research.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Answer (score -3):

"You can't go home again."

The sentiment of feeling unwelcome or uneasy in your hometown, or simply disliking it, is often referenced by quoting or mis-quoting the title of Thomas Wolfe's novel, "You can't go home again."  Wolfe's novel deals with an author who writes a best-selling book about his hometown and as a result finds himself unwelcome there.
See an example in this clip from Gross Point Blank: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgLr6qlpec4.

reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can%27t_Go_Home_Again